# How do you create a square of order numbers: array within array, bingo cards and loop gotchas…

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm posting what should be a very simple problem, but I'm having a hard time figuring out where I'm going wrong.

I'm trying to create a bingo card *n x n* in size.  Thus there will be an array of length *n* (the lines, top to bottom), each element of which would contain another array of length *n* (the individual squares), each element of which would contain an object to describe the state of that square (the number, whether it has been found or not).  As proof of concept I'm simply populating the squares with the numbers 1 to *n x n* and will shuffle the numbers later. Thus:

```
bingo = {
    card: [],

    createCard: function (size) {
        this.card.length = 0; // empty card
        size = Math.abs(+size) || 15; // should be positive and greater than 0

        let lineArray = [];

        for (let i = 0, n = 0; i < size; i++) {
            lineArray.length = 0;
            for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {

                lineArray.push({line: i, num: ++n, checked: false});
            }
            this.card.push(lineArray);
        }
    }
}
    bingo.createCard(15);
```

The problem is that each of the lines is the same. This happens at each *i* -- the entire card is filled with lines of identical values,

```
[ { line: 1, num: 16, checked: false },
    { line: 1, num: 17, checked: false },
    { line: 1, num: 18, checked: false },
    { line: 1, num: 19, checked: false },
    { line: 1, num: 20, checked: false },
    { line: 1, num: 21, checked: false },
    { line: 1, num: 22, checked: false },
    { line: 1, num: 23, checked: false },
    { line: 1, num: 24, checked: false },
    { line: 1, num: 25, checked: false },
    { line: 1, num: 26, checked: false },
    { line: 1, num: 27, checked: false },
    { line: 1, num: 28, checked: false },
    { line: 1, num: 29, checked: false },
    { line: 1, num: 30, checked: false } ] ]
```

ending with the final card being filled with 15 lines of

```
[ { line: 14, num: 211, checked: false },
    { line: 14, num: 212, checked: false },
    { line: 14, num: 213, checked: false },
    { line: 14, num: 214, checked: false },
    { line: 14, num: 215, checked: false },
    { line: 14, num: 216, checked: false },
    { line: 14, num: 217, checked: false },
    { line: 14, num: 218, checked: false },
    { line: 14, num: 219, checked: false },
    { line: 14, num: 220, checked: false },
    { line: 14, num: 221, checked: false },
    { line: 14, num: 222, checked: false },
    { line: 14, num: 223, checked: false },
    { line: 14, num: 224, checked: false },
    { line: 14, num: 225, checked: false } ],
```

this has to be a loop gotcha -- or some tragic error in my code -- but I don't see it after much time pondering.  Where lies the error?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: if `line` is supposed to update for each row, but be the same across cards, use `j`: `lineArray.push({line: j /* <-- changed from i to j*/, num: ++n, checked: false});`  i is the card number, j is the line number of each card.

Comment: should the lines and numbers start with one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have for every loop a new array, without referencing the old array.

Move

```
let lineArray = [];
```

inside of the first `for` loop.

```js
var bingo = {
        card: [],
        createCard: function (size) {
            this.card.length = 0; // empty card
            size = Math.abs(+size) || 15; // should be positive and greater than 0
            for (let i = 0, n = 0; i < size; i++) {
                let lineArray = [];
                for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                    lineArray.push({
                        line: i,
                        num: ++n,
                        checked: false
                    });
                }
                this.card.push(lineArray);
            }
        }
    };

bingo.createCard(15);

console.log(bingo.card);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A shorterapproach is to create the new Arrays and map the objects.

```js
var bingo = {
        card: [],
        createCard: function (length) {
            length = Math.abs(+length || 15);
            this.card = Array.from(
                { length },
                (_, i) => Array.from(
                    { length },
                    (_, j) => ({ line: i, num: i * length + j, checked: false })
                )
            );
        }
    };

bingo.createCard(15);

console.log(bingo.card);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, of course, it's lineArray is always the same array!  If you have a moment, could you give some insight into the second code snippet?  I understand that Array.from produces an array from an iterable, but I'm not clear what's going on here.  What, for example, does "(_, i)" mean?  It's the parameters for the arrow function, but what is "_" ?

Comment: @Cerulean the `(_,i)` means that the first parameter is ignored. Used in several functional languages such as F# pattern matching. You could just as well do `(ignored,i)` [Array from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) takes a function as second parameter so that function is used to create the values for the array.

Comment: the second parameter of `Array.from` is for a mapping function, as of [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). `(_, i)` is a function's head with two parameters, `_` and `i`. the underscore is a regular character for a variable, in this case it denotes an unused variable, because for the inner part only `i` or `j` is used.

Comment: Thanks.  If I look at the definition for _Array.from_, _Array.from(arrayLike[, mapFn[, thisArg]])_, then for the code above, _{length}_ would be the arrayLike object?  It's like this example then, but I'm still not clear how the object, with property _length_, is an iterable.  If you have a moment to explain, I'd be grateful! ||||      

     // Generate a sequence of numbers
    // Since the array is initialized with `undefined` on each position,
    // the value of `v` below will be `undefined`
    Array.from({length: 5}, (v, i) => i);
    // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: ES5:  Array.apply(null, { length: length }).map(/* the mapping function */),

Comment: Oh, I see, and _{length}_ is array-like _because_ we're giving it the property _length_ -- it has to be that name.  Got it.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to reset lineArray by using:
`lineArray.length = 0;`

This won't work, you'll need to do `lineArray = [];` instead, to actually reset it

Comment: Thanks! So obvious now that I see it!